# How to generate a .doc using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

today i need some help, i know its not that hard and there is a lot of help for doing this in php in this site but i couldn't find nothing with AJAX, the technology im learning now and i want to master some day.

My code is the following.

```
$(".descarga").click(function(){
    var paquete={idArchivo:$(this).val()};
    $.post("includes/descargarPublicacion.php",paquete,procesarDatos);
});
```

So when a buttom from the "descarga" class i make a "packet", which i use it with the post method to send the data to the php file called descargarPublicacion.php

This is how it looks the php file:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "registroflashback");
if (isset($_GET['idArchivo'])) {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.msword");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate,post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-disposition:attachment;filename=yeaboi.doc");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $idPubliGet=$_GET['idArchivo'];
    $resultadoBusqueda=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE idPubli='$idPubliGet'");
    if ($resultadoBusqueda->num_rows>0) {
        //$resultadoBusqueda['titulo'];
        echo 'descarga exitosa';
    }else{
        echo 'descarga no exitosa';
    }
}else{
    echo 'descarga no exitosa';
}
?>
```

I made a little research and people told me to use the headers to convert the file and download it, but it dosnt works for me, it dosnt generates any file, however it executes the "echo descarga exitosa" which i use as return value for the following function in the js file.

```
function procesarDatos(datos_devueltos){
    alert(datos_devueltos);
    if(datos_devueltos=="descarga exitosa"){
        $("#alertaDescarga").show(1000);
    }
    if(datos_devueltos!="descarga exitosa"){
         $("#alertaDescargaError").show(1000);
    }
}
```

How i could generate a .doc file from html using ajax and jquery? I know i have it almost, it should be some detail but i dont know which one is, thats why im asking some experienced help! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you want to to serve the .doc file via ajax. In my opinion it's easier to just provide valid .doc over a normal GET Request.

```
$(".descarga").click(function(){
    //onClick transfer id via Get-Param and download file
    window.location = "includes/descargarPublicacion.php?idArchivo="+$(this).val();
});
```

php part (descargarPublicacion.php)

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['idArchivo'])) {
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.msword");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate,post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-disposition:attachment;filename=yeaboi.doc");
    header("Expires: 0");

    //ID is available via GET because we send it as Url Param
    $idPubliGet=$_GET['idArchivo'];

    //@TODO fetch relevant data with given ID

    //@TODO generate valid(!) doc File output 
    //- just echo'ing something will not result in an valid document for Word
    echo $coumentContent;       
}
?>
```

To provide/generate a valid Word document is a little bit more complicated. I would recommend you to look into a libary which does all the work for you.
E.g. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

If you instead want to serve just some simple `.txt` File - change your header `Content-Type` to `text/plain` and the filename to `yeaboi.txt` and print/echo out the text-content

Comment: Yes i know there is a simplier way, but im starting to use ajax and i want to try it in every condition and situation, In this case what i want to do is , when i click a button attached to a div, which contains info about a file, to download it without moving from the site or modifying the url. Also, when i press it, it gives a pop up which says the result of the request, if successful or not. I think u understand it more. Btw ty for the library i will give it a try tomorrow :))

Comment: just for additional info - downloading a file with ajax is not that easy, because javascript is not able to save the file to your local computer. But keep an eye on this blog entry http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/ - I've not tried it out, but the demo looks nice and maybe it's something for you